# Monitor Scylla db using Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus, scylla

I have installed scylla db in Server A.

Installed Prometheus and Grafana in Server B.

Monitoring the scylla db server resource(CPU , RAM , Disk perfromance ..,) using **node exporter** ( installed node exporter in Server A).

Need to monitor scylla db operations using Prometheus and Grafana(from Server B).

What are all the exporters needs to be installed in Server A , and dashboard needed for scylla db monitoring in Grafana

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two kinds of metrics relevant for the ScyllaDB monitoring stack:

a) Internal DB metrics. ScyllaDB exports prometheus metrics natively. So you don't need anything extra running in Server A for those to work. All you need to do is point to the server(s) in the `scylla_servers.yml` file from the monitoring side.

b) Linux metrics (disk utilization, network, etc). That is what node_exporter is for. So just make sure node_exporter is running in ServerA, and point to that server again in the `node_exporter_servers.yml`  in the monitoring side.

In a lot of situations, of course, those two will be identical - only the ports differing (the exception is containerized environments where there are multiple ScyllaDB servers in a single Linux hosts). To fast track that case, Scylla Monitoring ships a script `genconfig.py`, which will generate `node_exporter_servers.yml` and `scylla_server.yml` with the correct ports given just a list of IPs of the servers running Scylla.

Comment: Also, you can take the predefined dashboards provided in the Scylla Grafana solution from here:
https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-grafana-monitoring